# TypeError: 'DiGraph' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, attributes, networkx, graph-theory

### Context

While trying to set an attribute in a directional graph of in networkx, so not a node attribute but a graph attribute, I experienced the following error:

```
 File "/some_path/some_filepy", line 81, in add_result_to_last_graph
    snn_graphs[-1]["result"] = result_per_type
TypeError: 'DiGraph' object does not support item assignment
```

I did not quickly find an example on how to store attributes in a networkx graph in [the documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/digraph.html), so wondered:

### Question

How can I store an attribute in a `nx.DiGraph()` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been encountered before by me, yet I did not find a specific solution for the networkx graph attribute setting in stackoverflow, so here is a way to store attributes in a `nx.DiGraph` object:

```
some_graph=nx.DiGraph()
some_attribute="pancakes"
# Store the attribute in the graph:
some_graph.graph["the_attribute_name"] = some_attribute
```

so in short, the syntax to store attributes in a graph, is: `<graphname>.graph`.

One can then print the graph attribute with:

```
print(some_graph.graph["the_attribute_name"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is something that helps, but you could also instantiate the graph with the desired attribute:

```py
from networkx import DiGraph
some_graph=DiGraph(some_attribute="pancakes")
some_graph.graph
# {'some_attribute': 'pancakes'}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you yes, this question was in particular for the case that the attribute is not yet computed at the time of graph creation, but it is nice to have it included here for completeness.